# Cron jobs showing pending status

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

its been 2 days now all cron jobs and cron_schedual showing pending status.
Any solution to run them normally ?

Comment: are you getting emails ( transnational etc )

Comment: @Naveed  few functionalities are working but not all. SO I truncate  cron_schedual . after that all cron job status is pending

Comment: did you try to run cron manually from server ?

Comment: @Naveed  I install a extension due to which I was enable to run a specifc cronjob so I run all its working. But not running cron jobs automatically.   So I truncate table after that all are pending

Comment: Then you should check that module, since that module is overriding default cron functionalities i guess. however there should be also option to run cron automatically.

Comment: @Naveed  I uninstall it now using composer.  Is there any way to make cron job run normally ?

Comment: Yes, you have to set cron in your hosting account and define timings at what time / minute these eshould run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74613/discussion-between-naveed-and-learner).

Comment: @Naveed  sorry I was away you there now ?

Comment: you there @Naveed ?

Comment: @Naveed can you post it as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showing under pending status, as seems cron is not working properly make sure cron is setup and scheduled on your server.

If you have server cpanel access, then Login to cpanel / server and search for cron_tabs and see if cron is set-up and path are defined accurately.

However if you have also/only SSH access you can still setup by follow commands / steps which are listed on magento dev docs:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

NOTE if you are using php multi-version on your server then you should execute commands with proper php library i.e :

**/usr/bin/php7.0** bin/magento

hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: you are <3 brother

Comment: @Learner, glad to help :)

Comment: brother I need a small help If you are available ?

Comment: Yes, i am available on chat

Answer (score 3):

I have also been stuck on this for a long time. The Magento 2 `cron_schedule` table has 20 entries for the same task. It seems it is generating every task for every minute that it is scheduled for but only completes the first one. I think we finally figured it out. After making the following settings.

- Set cron job in cpanel to run once per minute.
- set in STORES >> Configuration >> ADVANCED >> SYSTEM >> CRONS -use separate process to "no"
- then truncate the `cron_schedule` table

Now all tasks complete!

See this post for screen shots and more detail I hope this helps someone!
https://toweringmedia.com/blog/magento-2-cron-job-pending-jobs-never-cleared-solved/